# Node.js Debugger ends as soon as it is attached

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm, pm2

I'm currently using WebStorm as IDE and my project uses pm2 as process manager. The structure of my ecosystem is the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'myProject',
  cwd: __dirname,
  script: 'npm',
  args: 'run start:debug',
};
```

which executes

```json
"start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json"
```

As soon as the project starts, the terminal throws:

```txt
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/24bd6549-1601-4b0d-9e36-495765176abc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

I then press the Debug button in WebStorm with the following configuration:

[image]

After that the terminal shows this and the project starts without debugger:

```txt
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/24bd6549-1601-4b0d-9e36-495765176abc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
Debugger ending on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/24bd6549-1601-4b0d-9e36-495765176abc
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

My node version:

```txt
nvm current -> v14.20.1
```

Yesterday it worked fine, today I turned on my PC and it is broken, nothing on my environment has changed that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It turns out the last version of WebStorm, 2022.3.3, broke the WebStorm debugger, I had to go back to version 2022.3.2.

Comment: Try 2022.3.4 when it will be released (or current 2023.1 EAP/Beta builds) -- it *should* do better there. If you have a time of course.

Comment: Both 2022.3.2 and 2023.1 EAP fixed this for me, thanks!

Comment: I spent so much time wondering whether it was the chrome update that broke. Downgrading worked fine.

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/10524633222162/comments/10526858015250

Comment: Downgrading to 2022.3.2 worked.

Comment: I was about to break the laptop, downgrading saved me, thanks =)

Comment: downgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.5 (Ultimate Edition) worked for me. Upgrading to the latest 2023.1 Release Candidate build (For IDEA) did not work.

Answer (score 2):

2023.3.4 was just released and should fix this issue.